# Asus fx553vd keyboard led brightness hotkeys not working

Tags: 16.04, kernel, shortcut-keys, asus, keyboard-backlight

I have an Asus fx553vd laptop with the very recent mainline kernel(4.13.9), bios: GL553VD.302 and ubuntu 16.04

All the hotkeys on the keyboard work and also show On-Screen-Notification.
But on pressing fn + f3/f4 (keyboard backlight imllumination), only On-Screen_Notification is shown and nothing happens.

I've also tried checking through acpi_listen. But acpi_listen gives no output when fn + f3/f4 are pressed. Also tried the different grub cmd options, eg: "acpi_osi=", "acpi_backlight=", but nothing is working.

Please can someone point me in the right direction, as to how to make these two keys work.

Edit:
I have checked the /sys/class/leds directory, and there is no directory named kbd_backlight.
There is a phy0-led directory though. But all the files in it are blank. eg: brightness, max_brightness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Linux kernel version to 4.15.0. It has solved my fn + f3/f4 (keyboard back-light) issue. My Current kernel information is as below

> uname -a

```
Linux asus-GL553VE 4.15.0-041500rc1-generic #201711262030 SMP Mon Nov 27 01:32:09 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```